# async_std 1.8 has unresolved imports for items in `async_std::channel`

Tags: rust, rust-async-std

I'm building an application using async_std but this returns an unresolved import error:

```rust
use async_std::sync::Sender;
```

After looking at the documentation for 1.8.0, it seems like `async_std::sync` has been [deprecated](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.8.0/async_std/sync/fn.channel.html) in favor of `async_std::channel`. This was not the case in [1.7.0](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.7.0/async_std/sync/fn.channel.html).

After updating to 1.8.0, I tried to replace `use async_std::sync::Sender;`   with `use async_std::channel::Sender`.

The documentation seems to agree that it should work, but I still get an unresolved import error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the `unstable` feature:

```
async-std = { version = "1.8.0" , features = ["unstable"] }
```

The documentation informs you of this about `async_std::sync` in both 1.7 and 1.8:

[image: docs showing unstable requirement]

Unfortunately, in 1.8, `async_std::channel` *always* exists, but it [only re-exports the contents when `unstable` is present](https://github.com/async-rs/async-std/blob/v1.8.0/src/channel.rs):

```rust
//! Channels

#[cfg(feature = "unstable")]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "docs", doc(cfg(unstable)))]
#[doc(inline)]
pub use async_channel::*;
```

Comment: Yeah it seems like async_std::channel is unstable too, must be missing from the doc

Comment: I stated that I used the new async_std::channel api